# How to Distinct or Supress detail in Group Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, distinct, formula

I have 3 nested group and I want to distinct 3rd group's detail, I tried to use total running, summary, etc. But I still failed to solve this case, this is the data in my report.

```
1st Group
   2nd Group
     3rd Group - a(the data)
       Detail a
       Detail b
       Detail c
     3rd Group - b(the data)
       Detail a
       Detail b
       Detail c
```

that is my case, so i need the ouput be

```
1st Group
   2nd Group
     3rd Group - a(the data)
     3rd Group - b(the data)
       Detail a
       Detail b
       Detail c
```

I don't know how to supress detail if 3rd Group Record is not first Record.

Answer (score 0):

assume the field used to group on third field is called data3

detail record suppression formula

```
{data3} <> minimum({data3},{data3})
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, but when i modified my formula like that.. the result is still same.. btw is it posible to make '3rd group - 1st data, 3rd group - 2nd data'